# TortoiseSVN : Error running context: “An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions”

Tags: svn, windows-10, phpstorm, tortoisesvn

I can't use my tortoiseSVN or my PHP Storm Svn,
each time I get this message on Tortoise :

> Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   Error: Error running context: Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite
>   Error:  par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée.

which means :

> Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   Error: Error running context: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

And in PHP Storm it takes a lot of time and after I am asked to put my logins again.

I am on Windows 10, I have Tortoise 1.10.0.

Where does it comes from ?

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue or something?

Answer (score 1):

I come across same error message in TortoiseSVN today, with repository create in VisualSVN Server.

URL: https://TW2018079:8443/svn/prj, 'TW2018079' in my local computer name, and it is the URL specified in VisualSVN Server.

When I change the URL to https://192.168.3.27:8443/svn/prj, '192.168.3.27' is my local ip address.

By the way, I have set up both the VisualSVN and TortoiseSVN in the same Window 10 machine.

If you want the repository to be access by other people, Port Forwarding need to be configed in your Router.

Answer (score 1):

If the VPN has not connected, then you might get this error. So, kindly check the VPN connection on your desktop/laptop.